# How to change a topic name

Tags: ros, urg-node, hokuyo, hokuyo-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I have two laser scanner and I want drive these with urg_node but I do not know how to change the topic name that urg_node published the laser scanner data.

I want to get data from two laser scanner in two different topic.

I didn't find any parameter that changes the topic name.

any suggestion about this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131071/how-to-change-a-topic-name/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can be done to any node with [Topic Remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) ([with roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap)).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-02-20**:
thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@DanLazewatsky is correct, and his solution is likely the more-common use case.  But it is also worth mentioning the [topic_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools) package.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-02-23**:
thanks man :)